# python- extract html table without lossing axis titles

Tags: html, python-2.7, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, extract

Q1. Is there any way to extract data from the table but still able to track back the axis titles?
Q2. which approach will be better to extract data from a html table? HTMLParser or beautifulsoup or else?

i was trying to extract this income table
http://investing.businessweek.com/research/stocks/financials/financials.asp?ticker=TSCO:LN

i would like to to be

> "Currency in Millions of British Pounds","2009","2010","2011","2012"
>
> "Revenues",    "53,898.0", "56,910.0", "60,455.0", "64,539.0"
>
> "TOTAL REVENUES", "53,898.0", "56,910.0", "60,455.0", "64,539.0"

in the meantime i want to know "56,910.0" is the revenue in 2009

but i experienced two issues:

1. HTMLParser.HTMLParseError: malformed start tag, at line 1148, column 47 or
   HTMLParser.HTMLParseError: bad end tag: "", at line 225, column 104
2. cant keep track of the axis titles

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done quite a bit of scraping and BeautifulSoup rarely disappoints.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup 
URL = "http://investing.businessweek.com/research/stocks/financials/financials.asp?ticker=TSCO:LN"
from urllib import urlopen
HTML = urlopen ( URL )
soup = BeautifulSoup ( HTML )
statement = soup . find ( 'table', { 'class' : "financialStatement" } )
rows = statement . findAll ( 'tr' )
```

At this point I think you will find that rows has a length of 25 and that its first item is the header and last is the final row of the desired table.

Comment: i did install BeautifulSoup but it got this error:ImportError: cannot import name BeautifulSoup

Comment: @user2158132 If I recall correctly, BeautifulSoup is not part of the standard library. Do `pip install bs4` (the latest version)